# Tensorflow Intel MKL Optimization with NHWC data format

Tags: tensorflow, intel-mkl, intel-tensorflow, intel-ai-analytics

**TensorFlow** is compiled with the **Intel MKL** optimizations, many operations will be optimized and support NCHW.

Can someone please explain, why does Intel MKL support NCHW format more than NHWC?

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow default NHWC format is not the most efficient data layout for CPU and it results in some additional conversion overhead.Hence Intel MKL support NCHW format

Comment: Can you please explain in brief? If possible

Answer (score 2):

MKLDNN will run most of its compute-heavy math on a custom (Blocked) memory layout, and the conversion from NCHW --> blocked takes similar time to NHWC --> blocked. So there should be no difference for pure MKLDNN primitive accelerations. The difference is in some of the GEMM-based math, which works on the NCHW format by default, meaning that some matmul calls will NOT require layout conversions if input format is NCHW.